# Holomorphic functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let us consider the set $$\mathcal{O}_0(\mathbb{C}\backslash K) =\{f \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}\backslash K) : \lim_{z\to \infty}f(z) =0\}.$$ Do we agree that the map $$\mathcal{O}_0(\mathbb{C}\backslash K) \ni f \mapsto [f] \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}\backslash K)/\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$$ is an isomorphism ? It is injective by Liouville's theorem and surjective by substracking the principal part at infinity. Thank you for any confirmation !

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}\backslash K)/\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ does not make sense (or is at least an abuse of notation). You have a restriction map $r_K : \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}\backslash K)$ (which is injective) and you certainly mean $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}\backslash K)/r_K(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}))$.

Comment: Yeah, I mean two functions are equivalent if the difference is extensible to $\mathbb{C}.$